# Count Down Timer shows NaN

Tags: javascript, timer, count

I'm having a problem with a count down timer made in JavaScript. It was working for the last 2 weeks, but today it started to show NaN:NaN... , and I can't understand why. Here is the code, does anyone have any idea which one could be the problem?

```js
<div id="countdownmain">
<span id="countdownmain" class="timer"></span>
</div>


<script>

var date = new Date;

var secondsnow = date.getSeconds();
var minutesnow = date.getMinutes();
var hournow = date.getHours();
var day = date.getDay();
    
var passatti = (secondsnow + (minutesnow*60) + (hournow*3600));
if((day==1)||(day==2)||(day==3)||(day==4)){
    if(passatti < 46800){
       var upgradeTime = 46800 - passatti;
    }else if(passatti > 46800){
       var upgradeTime = 86400 - passatti + 46800;
    }
}else if((day==5)&&(passatti < 46800)){
   var upgradeTime = 46800 - passatti;
}else if((day==5)&&(passatti > 46800)){
   var upgradeTime = 86400 - passatti + 46800 + 86400 + 86400;
}else if((day==6)){
   var upgradeTime = 86400 - passatti + 46800 + 86400;
}else if((day==7)){
   var upgradeTime = 86400 - passatti + 46800;
}



var seconds = upgradeTime;
function timer() {
    
    var now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    
('0' + 11).slice(-2)

    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdownmain').innerHTML = "<span class='timesm'> For same working day dispatch, order in  &nbsp; </span><br class='appear'><span style='display:inline-block; width:45px;'><span class='hideDays glowW'>" + ('0' + days).slice(-2) + "</span></span><span class='times'> days </span><span style='display:inline-block; width:45px;'><span class='hideHours glowW'>" + ('0' + hours).slice(-2) + "</span></span><span class='times'> hours </span><span style='display:inline-block; width:45px;'><span class='hideMinutes glowW'>" + ('0' + minutes).slice(-2) + "</span></span><span class='times'> minutes </span><span style='display:inline-block; width:45px;'><span class='hideSec glowW'>" + ('0' + remainingSeconds).slice(-2) + "</span></span><span class='times'> seconds </span>";
    



    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        //document.getElementById('countdownmain').innerHTML = "Completed";
        seconds = upgradeTime;
    } else {
        seconds--;
        $('.hideSec').fadeOut('slow');
    }


if(('0' + remainingSeconds).slice(-2)==00){
$('.hideMinutes').fadeOut('slow');
}

if((('0' + minutes).slice(-2)==00)&&(('0' + remainingSeconds).slice(-2)==00)){
$('.hideHours').fadeOut('slow');
}

if((('0' + hours).slice(-2)==00)&&(('0' + minutes).slice(-2)==00)&&(('0' + remainingSeconds).slice(-2)==00)){
$('.hideDays').fadeOut('slow');
}


}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eek99mc3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, today is Sunday! [Javascript return 0 value as first of a week](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) in `getDay()`.

Take a look my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkiimm/wop51vw0/3/). I just decreased day comparator value in `if` statement. (e.g. 1 -> 0, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2 and so on..)